# Shipping app with a video/x-flv decoder

Tags: windows, windows-7, flv, ffdshow

I have an application that needs to play `video/x-flv` files. Not all customers have codecs installed, and codecs for `video/x-flv` are not shipped with Windows, so I have to ship it with my app.

The problem is I can't manage to understand what I need to ship in order to enable `video/x-flv` decoding on a fresh computer, which didn't install any codec packs.

I've tried installing [`ffdshow`](http://ffdshow-tryout.sourceforge.net/) and [`FLVSplitter`](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/Flash_Video_Splitter.htm), but without luck.

Installing the [`Combined Community Codec Pack`](http://www.cccp-project.net/) works - but I don't want to ship my app with a full codec pack, but with the minimum required to decode `video/x-flv`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gabest's`FLVSplitter` is not longer supported on Windows 7 systems.

There are two solutions:

1. Install the [`LAV Filters`](http://code.google.com/p/lavfilters/).
2. Compile your own tiny binary of [`libavformat`](http://www.ffmpeg.org/libavformat.html) (in case your framework using a binary as it's backend).

Because the LAV Filters themselves are ~7MB, and CCCP is ~9MB, I decided to install the whole codec pack on the users' computer (with their approval, of course).